# Application is not loaded completely during selenium automation

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

When many test cases are running for continuously for about 1 hour some of the pages in application is not loading completely. Selenium webdriver screenshot shows cropped images of the pages in application.This happens only with IE. I am using Selenium Webdriver with Java. Is it because of any performance issue with JVM or IEDriver? Will the working of IEDriver for long time effect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [performance monitoring](https://www.maketecheasier.com/windows-8-performance-monitor-to-analyse-system/) the client during the test? Look for virtual memory growth indicating memory leaks.

I routinely add [elapsed time measures](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-measure-elapsed-execution-time.html) to my tests to record how long between clicking a button and the following page being available for use. I like to look at the trend; is the performance a problem all at once or is it degrading gradually?

Lastly, are you taking [screenshots](http://watirmelon.com/2012/11/13/are-your-ie-webdriver-tests-running-slow-maybe-its-the-screenshots/)? You should only take them on a scenario failure.

Comment: Which IEDriver are you using, 32-bit or 64-bit?  Which version of IE are you simulating? Which version of Windows  (e.g. 8.1, 10) is the test running on?